# WP8 Panorama Width

Tags: windows-phone-8, width, panorama-control

I am developing a book reading application. I have used panorama control to present pages in book. Panorama control shows some little piece from the next panorama as you can see from this link:

http://photos.expertreviews.co.uk/images/front_picture_library_Expert_Reviews/dir_355/er_photo_177982_52.jpg

I need to expand the panorama size to stretch width of a panorama to width of page. (So that, piece from next page would not be visible). I have tried to set width and margins from the panoramaitemtemplate but couldn't succeed. How can I do it?

Comment: Showing a piece of next item is a characteristic of Panorama. Why don't use Pivot controls instead? Anyway, you can try by setting Panorama Item's orientation to Horizontal, and playing with the width.

Comment: I am facing the same problem any solution?

Comment: No, switched to Pivot Control.